# How to persist @OneToMany and @ManyToOne from Json

Tags: java, json, spring, one-to-many, many-to-one

I have next JSON:

```
{   
    "name": "String",
    "time": int,
    "serve": int,
    "type": "String",
    "about": "String",
    "userId": int,
    "food": [{
        "main_id": long
        "name_Id": int,
        "size": int,
        "measure": "String",
        "foodImgId": int

    },
    {
        "main_id": long
        "name_Id": int,
        "size": int,
        "measure": "String",
           "foodImgId": int 
    }, ... ],
    "steps": [{
        "main_id": long
        "step_id": int,
        "step": "String",
        "stepImgId": int

    },
    {
        "main_id": long
        "step_id": int,
        "step": "String",
        "img": int
    }, ... ],
    "img": [{
        "main_id": long
        "foodImgId": int,
        "stepImgId": int,
        "imgLink": "String"

    },
    {
        "main_id": long
        "foodImgId": int,
        "stepImgId": int,
        "imgLink": "String"
    }, ... ],
}
```

And next models for this JSON:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "MAIN")
public class Main implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "TIME", nullable = false)
    private int time;

    @Column(name = "SERVE", nullable = false)
    private int serve;

    @Column(name = "TYPE", nullable = false)
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "ABOUT", nullable = false)
    private String about;

    @Column(name = "USER_ID", nullable = false)
    private int userId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "main_id", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Food> food;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "main_id", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Steps> steps;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "main_id", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Image> img;

// setter & getter

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "STEPS")
public class Steps implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "MAIN_ID", updatable = false)
    public Main main_id;

    @Column(name = "STEP_ID", nullable = false)
    public int step_id;

    @Column(name = "STEP", nullable = false)
    public String step;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "stepImgId", nullable = true)
    public Image stepImgId;

    // setter & getter

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "IMAGE")
public class Image implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "MAIN_ID", nullable = false)
    private Main main_id;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, mappedBy="foodImgId")
    @Column(name = "foodImgId", nullable = true)
    private Food food;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, mappedBy="cookStepId")
    @Column(name = "stepImgId", nullable = true)
    private CookStep cookStepId;

    @Column(name = "ImgLink", nullable = false)
    private String imgLink;

    // setter & getter

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "FOOD")
public class Food implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "MAIN_ID", nullable = false)
    private Main main_idain_;

    @Column(name = "NAME_ID", nullable = false)
    private int nameId;

    @Column(name = "SIZE", nullable = false)
    private int size;

    @Column(name = "MEASURE", nullable = false)
    private String measure;

    @Column(name = "foodImgId", nullable = true)
    private int foodImgId;
    // setter & getter

}
```

My question. How I can save that JSON to DB? Main_id, in each model, have to have id from Main class.
I have an empty repositories because I tried save data by default method `repo.save(My_JSON)`, but i can not receive id from main class. I need any ideas, because I don't have enough experience with spring-boot.

Comment: Is there a typing error on "Main" type in food and step ?  this seem to be the "Recipe" class. Out of that, the main problem to resolve is that your data is not a tree because of Image class that duplicates existing Food and Step object (for those reading wanting to go right to the point)

Comment: Pdem, when I try save that JSON by JPA, I get error what main_id is null in internal structure (food, step or image). I what to use JPA for save data to SQL DB.
PS: yes, I made some mistakes when I wrote my question. Now, I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 @JsonBackReference  // add this to prevent Jackson (json) infinite recursion problem
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="MAIN_ID", referencedColumnName = "main_id" ,updatable = false,insertable = false)
public Main main_id;
```

Possible you forgot to add referencedColumnName which is the name of the corresponding column in the database.

Comment: I haven't tried use annotation @JsonBackReference. Might it help me.

Comment: Please let me know if it worked. I took me a long time to find @JasonBackReference annotation. Why did you choosed FetchType.EAGER ?

Comment: Magdalena, I use FetchType.EAGER because I need all data from DB. Unfortunately, Your way doesn't work for me. I'm still getting null in food.main_id.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Also not that it matters, but interesting choice of naming one table MAIN. It might not clash with method public static void main (...) from the running application but it creates confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I run your example in SprinBoot using Hibernate so I suggest in Food
class to change line

```
private Main main_idain_
```

to

```
private Main main_id
```

That was the error I run into.

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, I found solution. My problem was what I couldn't get response which I need. I made one huge mistake. I did bidirectional connection and received loop and empty field. Finally my entities look next. I'll only show what changed. 
In the main:

```
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "RECIPE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Set<FoodEntity> foodEntity;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "RECIPE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Set<stepEntity> stepEntity;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "RECIPE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Set<ImageEntity> imageEntity;
```

In another entities, I removed annotation `@ManyToOne` and left only row where I define variable(but it need not everywhere) where it need for query.